# Change description of dynamically added field

Tags: 8, hooks, paragraphs

I'm trying to change the description of fields in a from (/node/add/content_type).

I found out it is possible to change the description with this code:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_thema_form') {
    $markDownDescription= 'custom description';
    $form['field_name']['widget'][0]['#description'] = \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup::create(t( $markDownDescription . $form['field_txt_lesinhoud']['widget'][0]['#description']));
  }
}
```

This works great on existing fields, but via Paragraphs I add new fields since they are loaded using AJAX they for some reason don't get the new description. Is there any way to do a new form alter to the new fields?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For paragraphs this is probably another form_id. Your hook catches them all, so this should be easy to debug.

Comment: When log the form_id i get one id also when I add a paragraph item. So it is the same.

Comment: Just set a breakpoint, yes, it is a the same form id, but the widget of the paragraph field is in a subform `$form['field_paragraph']['widget'][1]['subform']['field_name']['widget'][0]['#description']`

Comment: Okay, I got my breakpoints and am able to debug with Xdebug now. But the $form['field_paragraph']['widget'][1] is not available. And the subform can't be found anywhere and a search doesn't give me de field name of the field in the subform. So what am I doing wrong? Hope you can help me a bit further again. I have the feeling I'm almost there...

Comment: I've copied the path while adding a second paragraph. You probably need to iterate.

Comment: Hi 4k4, that sounds promissing but I don't know where to begin with this. Is it possible the help me a bit further with this, path copying and iterate thing? Do you maybe have an example piece of code? Everything is welcome.

Comment: Here I am again, I was hoping this was easier to solve but it's not working still. I found a way to see all subform fields. And I can go to '$subform['field_name‌​']['widget'][0]['#de‌​scription']' but this is a protected value so I can't change it. Any suggestions on this issue?

Comment: The protected values are inside of a markup object. You simply create a new markup object to overwrite the old one, like you already did for another field widget in the question.

Comment: That's what I thought but for some reason it doesn't work I use this line to overwrite but without any succes: `$subform['field_platte_tekst']['widget'][0]['#de‌​scription'] = \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup::create(t( $markDownDescription ));`

Comment: You only need t(), because this creates a markup object already (this is a shortcut for `new TranslatableMarkup()`)

Comment: I tried this `$subform['field_platte_tekst']['widget'][0]['#de‌​scription'‌​] = t( $markDownDescription );` as you suggested but the description is not changed.

Comment: I did some more research and found out that by doing this, it doesn't overwrite the old Description, it just adds a other Description to the array. Is this what is supposed to happen? I also found out there is a second Description at: `$subform['field_platte_tekst']['widget']['#de‌​scription'‌​‌​]`

Comment: I tried some more, and after a while I noticed that my IDE said there was a typo in the word 'de‌​scription'‌​‌​ when I copied the 'description' once more it didn't see the typo and it works. Thanks for your patience.

*While typing this, i copied the description from my previous comment and for some reason the pasted 'description' in this post also mentions a typo. Try it, copy and paste the description from above comment and paste it in the comment field. You will see a red line mentioning the typo, but I really can't see the problem. Maybe you can.